# How to import Arabic dump SQL file to phpmyadmin without problems?

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

Hey guys
I've converted a microsoft access database to use it in Mysql, the problem is there are some values in arabic, in the dump file they are fine, but when I import the database to phpmyadmin the arabic letters become like strange letters that can't be read, they are important in the database and I couldn't find a solution for that.
is there anything that I can do to fix this problem ?  and thank you very much :D

Comment: Looks like a question for serverfault. Anyway, check that your dump is in UTF8 and mhmmyadmin is set up to accept UTF8 dump. Also check your database and tables' encodings - it should also be UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your database, tables and fields collations to the right encoding. `utf8_unicode_ci` will probably be fine.

Comment: Should I set the encoding from phpmyadmin after I import the dump file ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the sql file, copy the entire sql from the file and paste it in the SQL box. execute these statements. it will work. but make sure the fields which is going to store the arabic data should be utf8 collated